# Economics Practice Homework Problem

Tags: probability

Working on probability theory in an economics class. This was on of the practice problems that I'm struggling to back up with math. Any help would be appreciated! :)

- An accident insurance company has reserves to cover claims on no more than 3 accidents. If all accidents have a probability of 0.01 of occurring, if all accidents are independent, and if the insurance company writes 100 policies, what
  is the probability that they will not have enough reserves?

Comment: @Andy: Have you tried anything so far? If so, it might be helpful to include it in your post.

Comment: Hint: Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Let's $X_i$ be a Bernoulli variable that is 1 if an accident occured with the policy number $i$, 0 otherwise. Thus we have:
$$P(X_i = 1) = 0.01, P(X_i = 0) = 0.99$$
This is true for all $i$ since we assume independance.

Let $Y = X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_{100}$ the sum of all $X_i$. $Y$ counts the number of accidents that occured.

That means you are looking for $P(Y > 3)$.

Now, if you are having probability class, you should have seen what a Bernoulli variable is, and what the distribution of a variable that is the sum of independant Bernoulli variables is.

If you don't know, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Please note that according to your question I had to made the assumption that the probability you give (0.01), is the probability that for 1 policy there will be 1 accident and that there cannot be more than 1 accident for the same policy. Usually, we give a probability that in a given amount of time there will be an accident.